# Cannot set array in Cells()

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to create an array to put specific rows which I want a value, but when I try to execute it returns me error 1004

```
Option Explicit
Sub teste()

Dim i
Dim myarray
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aa

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

myarray = Array(1, 2, 5, 7)


For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1
Next

End Sub
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` in your case is a counter that goes from `LBound(myarray)` which is `0` and `UBound(myarray)` which is `3`.  `i` is not the value in the array.  The value in the array is `myarray(i)`

So change the reference inside the loop:

```
Option Explicit
Sub teste()

Dim i
Dim myarray
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aa

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

myarray = Array(1, 2, 5, 7)


For i = LBound(myarray)+1 To UBound(myarray)+1
    ws.Cells(myarray(i), 1).Value = 1
Next

End Sub
```